# My French VLS-TS visa expired on 10 April, I applied for residence permit on 30 March, can I still visit Schengen countries?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, france, norway

I had a "Passport Talent" visa for France. The information written on the visa is:

- Valid for: France
- From: 11-12-22
- Until: 10-04-23
- Duration of stay: XXX
- Type of visa: D
- Number of entries: Mult
- Remarks: Pass. Talent; Chercheur; PT4 VLSTS; Valider en ligne

I have applied for a residence permit as my employer has extended my contract. I am unsure whether I can travel to other Schengen countries (especially Italy and Norway) based on the receipt of my resident permit application.

Comment: The rules are complicated. At least in some cases (I'm not sure about yours) it depends whether you have an *attestation* or a *récépissé*. And the rules are different for a first application vs renewal, and I don't know whether a residence permit after a *passeport talent* gives you the (more favorable) rules for renewal. Your employer's contact for visa matters or [expatriates.se] is more likely to know than [travel.se].